# how can I validate inside datatable for status column?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I want to validate if status == 1 then display active span if not display inactive status , but how can I do it with datatables I try it this with jquery ajax without datatables  `status = (Data[i][5] == 1)  ? "<span class='label label-success'>active</span>":"<span class='label label-danger'>inactive</span>";`

controller

```
public function datatable(){
        $array = $this->products->datatable();
        $this->json($array);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($array as $rows){
            array_push($data, array(
                $rows['id'],
                $rows['descripcion'],
                $rows['precio_compra'],
                $rows['precio_venta'],
                $rows['precio_mayoreo'],    
                $rows['existencia'],
                $rows['status']
            ));
        }
        $this->json(array('data' => $data));
    }
```

ajax

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthChange": false,
        ajax: {
            url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
            type: 'POST',
        },
        columnDefs:[{
            targets: -1,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "<button>Click!</button>"
        }],
    });
```

how can I validate change that one for span text??

[image: datatable]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested).

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthChange": false,
    ajax: {
        url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
        type: 'POST',
    },
    columnDefs:[{
        targets: -1,
        data: null,
        defaultContent: "<button>Click!</button>"
        },
        { 
        targets: 6,
        render : function(data, type, row) {
                return '<span class="label label-' + (data[6] == 1 ? 'success' : 'danger') + '">' + (data[6] == 1 ? 'active' : 'inactive') + '</span>'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**Edit:** Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znbjuet9/1/)

Comment: it works , but when I change 1 by 0 then use the same span with the name name by in danger , how can I fix it?